# iOS UIWebView - How to disable web page's swipe gestures (i.e. javaScript, etc)

Tags: ios, uiwebview, overriding, swipe

I am building a custom web browser in my app and use swipe gestures to move between collections of different URLs.
However, a lot of websites these days have "swipe gestures" embedded in their site to do things like slide photo galleries, open new urls, etc.

I was wondering if it is possible to disable these somehow, so I can ensure the swipe gestures only triggers my methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Assume something like this should work

```
UIWebView *webView = [UIWebView new];

UIGestureRecognizer *webPan;
for (UIGestureRecognizer *pan in webView.scrollView.gestureRecognizers) {
        webPan = pan;
    if ([webPan isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        webPan = nil;
    }
}
```

now that the pan gesture recognizer is gone from the `UIWebView`'s scrollview you can implement your own gesture recognizers.